# HTML select element with a custom arrow - text comes over the arrow

Tags: html, css

So, I have a HTML page with a select element which has a custom arrow. The problem is that the select element text comes over the arrow of the select element. I do not want that. The text should not come over the arrow.

**Please note:** I'm looking for a cross-browser solution.

Here is my CSS code. The default select arrow will be replaced with an own image.

```
div.pudotusvalikko {
  width: 95%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url(/kuvat/arrow22x22.gif); /* width 22 px and height 22 px */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}

div.seura {
  width: 224px;
}

div.pudotusvalikko select {
  border: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 110%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  background: transparent;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

And here is my HTML code. When the item "Default value of the list is this" is selected, its text will come over the custom select arrow.

```
<div class="pudotusvalikko seura">
  <select name="se1" id="se1">
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">GUU</option>
    <option value="3">PPP</option>
    <option value="4">SBK</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">Default value of the list is this</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How should I modify my code if I want that the item text "Default value of the list is this" will not come over the custom select arrow?

**Edit:**

As you can see here, the text comes over the background image. What should I do to fix this?

```css
div.pudotusvalikko {
  width: 95%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#fff;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random'); /* width 22 px and height 22 px */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-size:20px 20px;/*Add this*/
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}

div.seura {
  width: 224px;
}

div.pudotusvalikko select {
  border: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 110%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  background: transparent;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pudotusvalikko seura">
  <select name="se1" id="se1">
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">GUU</option>
    <option value="3">PPP</option>
    <option value="4">SBK</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">Default value of the list is this this this this this this this this this this this</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still looking for help...

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` menu comes from the operating system and browser UI, not your code. For example, on iOS the interface is completely different than on Windows or OS X.

If you want this behaviour you'll need to create a CSS or Javascript dropdown menu.

Comment: As you can see, I already have CSS code for a custom dropdown menu.

Comment: You can style the select element, but not the menu that appears on click.

Comment: When the page loads, I just want that the select text "Default value of the list is this" is not over the custom select arrow. That's all.

Comment: It's not, as far as I can see. http://jsbin.com/pobiko/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Yes, it's not. That's the problem. That's also the reason for posting this question here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set background-size for your image as in below codes,

```css
div{
  width: 330px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#fff;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
div::before{
  content:'';
  background:#f22;
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  top:10px;
  left:320px;
  z-index:9;
  pointer-events:none;
  background:url("https://source.unsplash.com/random");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:20px 20px;
}
select {
  border: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <select name="se1">
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">GUU</option>
    <option value="3">PPP</option>
    <option value="4">SBK</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">Default value of the list xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not help me. Please replace the text "Default value of the list is this" with a very long text and you will see that the text comes over the background image.

Comment: Do you have more ideas, @frnt?

Comment: @xms try updated code example, it works as needed. We have placed our image above arrow and used pointer-events. Pointer-events if set to none; then ignores the click event on assigned element.

Comment: No, when using IE 10.

Answer (score 0):

Add right padding instead of limiting the select width.

Comment: It seems to me that IE does not display right padding correctly.